# My jQuery function doesn't work in IE?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, function

It looks like my jQuery function doesn't work in IE 8 & 9.

I want to align a div with jQuery, so i created the following function:

```
imageAlign = function(){
    var image = $j(this); 
    var imageWidth = image.width();
    var imageMargin = imageWidth / 2;
    image.css("margin-right", -imageMargin);
};
$j('.image-wrap').each(imageAlign);
```

I use $j as jQuery.noConflict(); because of Wordpress.

In IE 8 & 9 the function works only on the first div with the class .image-wrap.

If i use the code without a function, it works fine in all browsers:

```
var image = $j('.image-wrap'); 
var imageWidth = image.width();
var imageMargin = imageWidth / 2;
image.css("margin-right", -imageMargin);
```

What am i doing wrong?

**Edit:**

My code is inside a document ready:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($j) {
        var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

        <!-- Code -->

});
```

**EDIT !important**

I think i asked the wrong question! With the answers below i discovered something else. In IE 8 and 9 the .image-wrap divs (except the first one) DO get a negativ margin-right. But the value of this negativ margin right isn't correct. So the function does work, but not correctly.

I'm sorry for taking your time... anyway, thanks for your help guys!

Comment: Is it inside the `$j(document).ready()` function?

Comment: Yep, otherwise the code without the function won't work right? (;

Edit: I will add the code to the question

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: The console is empty...

Comment: @wind Check out my latest edit, it should help.